# Cartesian rolling join with data.table

Tags: r, join, data.table

I'm not exactly sure how to describe this, but I'll gladly edit the title and/or post to reflect comments and answers.

**Problem**

I have two `data.frames` that I would like to merge with a combination of a left join, an outer join, and a rolling join.

- One of the key columns (`year`) is for the rolling join.
- Another key column (`cat`) is common to both `data.frames`. In the example below I've only supplied exemplary subsets of the full data, which has thousands of values for `cat`.
- The first `data.frame`, `X`, has an additional key column `cnty` (county), and the second `data.frame`, `Y`, has an additional key column `pol` (pollutant).
- For each group defined by `cat` and `year`, I would like the final result to contain a cartesian product of `cnty` and `pol`, with value columns `emfac` (from `X`) and `tput` (from `Y`). The goal is to be able to compute `emfac * tput`.

Here is an exemplary subset of `X`:

```
  cat year cnty  tput
1  29 2011  ALA 67852
2  29 2011   CC 33893
3  29 2011  MRN 11319
```

... and here is an exemplary subset of `Y`:

```
  cat year pol emfac
1  29 1975 TOG   2.4
2  29 1975  PM   5.3
```

**Closest attempt so far**

I can almost, but not quite, get the output I want:

```
X <- structure(list(
       cat = c(29L, 29L, 29L), 
       year = c(2011L, 2011L, 2011L), 
       cnty = c("ALA", "CC", "MRN"), 
       tput = c(67852, 33893, 11319)), 
       .Names = c("cat", "year", "cnty", "tput"), 
       class = c("data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))

Y <- structure(list(
       cat = c(29L, 29L), 
       year = c(1975, 1975), 
       pol = c("PM", "TOG"), 
       emfac = c(2.4, 5.3)),
       .Names = c("cat", "year", "pol", "emfac"), 
       class = c("data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L))

library(data.table)
X <- data.table(X, key = c("cat", "cnty", "year"))
Y <- data.table(Y, key = c("cat", "pol", "year"))
Y[X, roll = TRUE]

   cat year pol emfac cnty  tput
1:  29 2011  PM   5.3  ALA 67852
2:  29 2011  PM   5.3   CC 33893
3:  29 2011  PM   5.3  MRN 11319
```

This is my "nearest miss". Most of my other attempts are much more wrong.

**Expected result**

```
   cat year pol emfac cnty  tput
1:  29 2011  PM   5.3  ALA 67852
2:  29 2011  PM   5.3   CC 33893
3:  29 2011  PM   5.3  MRN 11319
4:  29 2011 TOG   2.4  ALA 67852
5:  29 2011 TOG   2.4   CC 33893
6:  29 2011 TOG   2.4  MRN 11319
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Why do your subsets not have the same years?  Do you want to join the group `cat = 29, year = 2011` to the group `cat = 29, year = 1975`?

Comment: Not sure, but seems like you're looking for: `X[Y, allow.cartesian=TRUE]` where the key column is `cat`.

Comment: @nacnudus that's the right idea. I want an equi-join on "cat" but a rolling join on "year". That is, for each (cat, year, cnty) in X I want the most recent (year, emfac) from Y where Y.year <= X.year. In the "desired result", year is the X.year from those matches.

Comment: @Arun I do want the cartesian of pol and cnty, but I want a rolling join on year (see comment above)

Comment: @dholstius you may fill the feature request on project's github page

Comment: In case you haven't found the solution I think this gives the desired output `X <- data.table(X, key = c("cat"))
Y <- data.table(Y, key = c("cat"))
XY <- X[Y, allow.cartesian=TRUE] XY[, .SD[which.max(i.year)], by = list(cat, year, cnty, pol)]`